# Deprecation warnings after switching to the webdrivers gem

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec

As suggested [here](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-he), I have replaced `chromedriver-helper` with `webdrivers` on a Rails 5.2 app with RSpec 3.8.

According to [this post](https://everydayrails.com/2019/04/09/chromedriver-helper-webdrivers.html), it should a simple replacement and after updating my `Gemfile` the specs work. However, I get a bunch of deprecation warnings

> 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (ensure the driver supports
>   W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23 13:33:02 WARN
>   Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the
>   driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead. 2019-04-23
>   13:33:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION]
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated.
>   Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure
>   the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.

The `Selenium Webdriver` has been updated to the latest version.

```
 -  selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
 +  selenium-webdriver (3.141.5926)
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Your question helped me. But your first link is broken, would you fix it? Did you mean this? https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/83

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I also experienced this issue when replacing `chromedriver-helper` with `webdrivers`, however updating Capybara to the latest version (3.18.0) resolved it.

Comment: I don't recommend suppressing the warnings. They exist for a reason! Without them, I wouldn't have found this answer and upgraded Capybara which solved a few other problems with it.

Comment: That's a fair point @karnesJ.R.  I've edited my answer to remove that detail as supressing warnings is not something i'd advocate - it was more there for reference.

Comment: I've got the same problem, but this didn't fix it for me. =\

Comment: I think the removed comment is still helpful. I'm trying to address deprecations I can control, but they get lost in the noise of these that I currently can't. Put this in an initializer: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :error` (the default is :warn)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem upgrading Capybara to 3.18 because of its dependency on regexp_parser 1.2, so I found that **downgrading** selenium-webdriver to 3.141.0 resolved the problem (presumably because that version had not yet deprecated those calls).