# (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.`

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, ruby-on-rails-6

I have read other postings with the same error, but none have given me a usable solution.

I have a rails app:

#### gem versions

```
Rails 6.0.2.1
ruby 2.6.5p114
```

#### Gem.lock

```
watir (6.16.5)
  regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 3.6)

selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
  childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
  rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
```

#### Chrome Driver

```
ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614})
```

When I do this with watir:

```
 browser.select_list(id:'car_type').select('ford')
 or
 browser.button(xpath: '//div/ul/li[2]/button').click
```

I get the following error, repeating, in a loop:

`WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.`

I assume I ams using the wrong command or the wrong webdriver.  How do I fix this issue? Where do I find the non-depreciated commends that replace the current commands?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55870879/3784008) and report back. It may be as simple as switching your gems and driver.

Comment: I don't have chromedriver-helper, at least I can not find it, where would I look? It's not in my gem.lock file.

Answer (score 0):

This error is absolutely not your problem. Watir still hasn't moved that completely. They would be replacing with the right Exceptions soon. But for the time being, if you don't want to see this warning, just go to

```
C:\Ruby26\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\watir-6.16.5\lib\watir\elements
```

where you would find element.rb file, search `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError` this exception and replace with `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError`, then you would not be notified with warning. You may ask me why they are giving the warning instead of replacing it, that's because some people still may use old chrome driver, that's why they are setting the warning message first and then they would replace the old exception with new exception according to W3C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Watir seems to not have been updated since 2018, and hence uses an older Selenium gem that you can not upgrade.

Therefore, I switched to Capybara and it fixed the issue. Not a true solution, but it was the easiest fix for my case.